# Obtaining Schegen visa for one country but never planning to go there

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I am from a fairly small country and need to travel to Italy for a conference. The problem is in my country we have no Italian embassy and the process of getting an Italian Schengen visa is a lengthy and arduous process since my passport has to be mailed to some other country to be stamped, and there's a lot of bureaucracy involved.

We do, however, have a German embassy and they are quite efficient. My question is can I obtain a German visa solely for the purpose of visiting Italy, without problems?

Comment: You can obtain it quite easily, by being untruthful. And you might not get caught. But it is wrong and there are consequences IF you are caught. I have previously done it about three times however I would not advise you to do so. You can be refused entry, blacklisted, etc plus it is unethical.

Comment: You did not mention your country. Have you checked if the Italians have empowered another Schengen embassy to handle their applications?

Comment: @SheikPaul: Wrong? Unethical? Those words don't apply to immigration decisions. The only questions are: Will I get caught? and What are the likely consequences? It's not a question of morals.

Comment: @TonyK That's the individuals choice to make. I believe stackexchange has some sort of understanding to promote lawful behavior.

Comment: @SheikPaul: 'Unlawful' is not the same as 'wrong' or 'unethical'. That's crazy talk.

Comment: @o.m. thank you for that comment! I checked with the German embassy and they do indeed issue Italian Schengen visas!

Answer (score 1):

According to the Schengen rules, a visa application must be filed with a representation of the member country that is a main destination for the proposed trip. Since Germany is not the main destination for your trip, they would be required to reject your application.

The only way to get your application processed by Germany would be to lie about your intentions. And if this lie is later uncovered (e.g. if you show up at the Italian border with no documentable plans to go to Germany), your visa can be annulled. You will then be refused entry, and it can become difficult to obtain another visa since your credibility has been harmed.

Comment: or to actually add a holiday in Germany onto the trip

Comment: @theotherone: The conference would still make Italy the main destination. Having a clear main _purpose_ in one member country trumps the longest-stay fallback rule.